# How can I order my UITableView Alphabetically?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I created a `UITableView` that gets its data from a txt.file.
However, although the txt-File is sorted alphabetically the UITableView is not.

Does anybody know how to order/sort it alphabetically?

I am using Swift 3 and Xcode 8.

```
var dictA = [String:String]()
var filtereddictA = [String:String]()
var visibleA = [ String ]()
var searchController =  UISearchController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "a", ofType:"txt")

    let filemgr = FileManager.default
    if filemgr.fileExists(atPath: path!) {
        do {
            let fullText = try String(contentsOfFile: path! ,encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

            let readings = fullText.components(separatedBy: "\n")

            for abteilungen in readings {
                let aData = abteilungen.components(separatedBy: "\t")

                if abteilungenData.count > 1 {
                    dictA[aData[0]] = aData[1]
                }
            }
            filtereddictA = dictA

        } catch let error {
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }

        searchController = UISearchController (searchResultsController: nil)
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()

        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

        definesPresentationContext = true
    }

    self.title = "A"

}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return filtereddictA.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    let key = Array(filtereddictA.keys)[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = key
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = filtereddictA[key]

    return cell
}

@available(iOS 8.0, *)
public func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    guard let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text?.lowercased() else {
        return
    }

    let keyPositions = Array(filtereddictA.keys)
    filtereddictA = [:]
    var removeArray = [ IndexPath ]()
    var addArray = [ IndexPath ]()
    for ab in dictA {
        if abteilung.key.lowercased().range(of: searchText) != nil || a.value.lowercased().range(of: searchText) != nil || searchText.isEmpty {
            filtereddictA[ab.key] = ab.value
        } else {
            if let index = keyPositions.index(of: abteilung.key) {
                removeArray.append(IndexPath(row: index, section: 0))
            }
        }
    }

    if removeArray.count > 0 {
        removeArray.sort(by: { (p1,p2) -> Bool in
            return p1.row > p2.row
        })
        tableView.deleteRows(at: removeArray, with: .bottom)
    }
    var i = 0
    for ab in filtereddictA.keys {
        if !keyPositions.contains(ab) {
            addArray.append(IndexPath(item: i, section: 0))
        }
        i += 1
    }
    if addArray.count > 0 {
        addArray.sort(by: { (p1,p2) -> Bool in
            return p1.row < p2.row
        })
        tableView.insertRows(at: addArray, with: .bottom)
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return filtereddictA.count
}
```

Comment: Please provide the code you are using to read the text file, the text file itself, and the table view datasource.

Comment: edited it @George Green

Comment: Dictionarys are not sorted, so when you call `Array(filtereddictAbteilungen.keys)[indexPath.row]` it creates an array from your dictionary keys but you do not sort them. You would be better served creating a simple struct to store your data (rather than key value pair) and sorting it once when you create it. Will post how to do this in a min.

Comment: See @Oleg's answer below, it gives you a sorted list of tuple values that you can use in your datasource.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your post

Answer (score 3):

You should set proper order of the elements in the data source.
I can make assumption that `filtereddictAbteilungen` is dictionary that is you're datasource.

So sort it firstly and that populate via `tableView`.

Example:

```
let dictionary = [
    "A" : [1, 2],
    "Z" : [3, 4],
    "D" : [5, 6]
]

let sortedKeys = dictionary.sorted(by: { $0.0 < $1.0 })
```

Comment: My datasource is a txt-File and the dict is called "dictAbteilungen" The array "filtereddictAbteilungen" is only the array that should show after searching for something with the search bar. I still don't really do how to do that :(

Comment: Try to sort dictAbteliungen first

Comment: Ok I will help you. now do this let sortedArray = dictAbteilungen.sorted(:by {$0.0 < $1.0}) and send sortedArray to tableView